# Shift Register Vs Multiplexer

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, verilog, vhdl, hardware

I am not sure about an implementation. I've a multiplexer 8 input, 1 output and 3 select signal. One of these selects signal sequentialy acquires all value of a bit vector. Now I can choose 2 way.

The first way is to use another multiplexer where the input is the bit vector and the select signal is a counter log2 of the input.

The second way is to use a shift register and take the LSB bit of the vector.

What is the best solution in terms of area in a FPGA

Comment: There are several open questions: What are you going to do with the result? Do you need the counter anyway? What platform are you using (4 or 6 input LUTs)? Are the bits in your byte in the right order or do you need 'random' access to the bits?

Comment: Ok, the bits are in the right order. I'm using the counter only to know when I've reach the end of my vector. About the platform the fpga uses LUT4. I don't understand what results  you mean. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: By 'result' I mean the output of your circuit (mux/shift register). For some optimizations, it's good to know how bits are consumed by the next circuit. -- A LUT4 architecture will need more space for the 8to1 mux than I described for the LUT6 architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some thoughts on hardware coasts:

**8 bit shift register on virtex-5, spartan-6**
A slices contains 4 LUTs and 4 registers. You'll need 2 slices to store 8 bits.

**8 bit shift register on virtex-6, 7-series**
A slice contains 4 LUTS and 8 registers. You can store the complete byte in one slice.

**3 bit counter**
Small counters are implemented using LUTs and registers. This counter fits into one slice

**8to1 multiplexer**
A 6-input LUT architecture can map 4to1 muxes into one LUT. A 8to1 mux requires two 4to1 muxes and one 2to1 mux (mux-tree). Xilinx FPGA slice cells contain additional F7MUX and F8MUX primitives which can be used to build wider muxes. In case of 8 bits: 2 LUTs and one F7MUX. All in all: A half of a slice.

### Note 1:

If you are using a shift-register, you also need to know when to stop shifting, if it's not a pipeline.

Comment: Thank you!!! I've done a synthesis and I see that I cannot use the shift register ( too many registers and too small free space. ). I'll try to use multiplexer approach. Thank you so much.